# Two motor cars with the same velocity v km/h from distance a km and b km respectively from the junction...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Two motor cars with the same velocity v km/h from distance a km and b km respectively from the junction of two roads inclined at right angle and travel towards the junction. Prove that after 2 hours, they are nearing each other at the rate of

$$\dfrac{4v^2-(a+b)v}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-4v(a+b)+8v^2}} km/h$$

I could not approach the problem much. Please help.

Comment: https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/two-motor-cars-start-with-the-same-velocity-v-km-hr-from-the/application-of-derivatives/3786080

Comment: @labbhattacharjee There seems to be a problem with the website, I cannot seem to access it even after logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to simplify the problem with mathematical language first.

Draw a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle ABC=90° \quad AB=a, AC=b$.

[image]

Now we have two points P, Q denoting the moving motor cars with $PB=a-v t$ and $QB=b-v t$.

If you want to calculate the rate they are getting near to each other, you first have to look for a expression of the distance between them, that is, distance between $P,Q$. Using Pythagorean's theorem, we have $PQ=\sqrt{PB^2+BQ^2}=\sqrt{(a-vt)^2+(b-vt)^2}$.

Now since we are looking for rate of change of $PQ$, we take its derivative with respect to $t$ (time), that is,
$\qquad PQ'=\dfrac{d}{dt}PQ=\dfrac{d}{dt}\sqrt{(a-vt)^2+(b-vt)^2}=\dfrac{(2t v-a-b) v}{\sqrt{2 t^2 v^2-2\cdot (a+b) t v+a^2+b^2}}$.

Plugging $t=2$ into $PQ'$ yields $$\dfrac{4v^2-(a+b)v}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-4v(a+b)+8v^2}} km/h$$ which is the correct answer.

(If you have problem looking for the derivative of $PQ(t)$, please ask :) )